# Select bitmap image from gallary and on button click save to Sdcard

Tags: android

hello very good noon to all.Actually i want to select an image from gallery and then i want to save the selected image in Sdcard which is available in android device.

Comment: Please give me the answer which will help me to solve my problem. please

Answer (score 1):

**pick image from Sd card:**

```
Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // comma-separated MIME types
            mediaChooser.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, RESULT_LOAD_WATER_IMAGE);
```

**And On Activity Result :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            String path;

            path = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());


        }
        break;


}
```

**Implementation Of getRealPathFromURI:**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}
```

**Save Image To Sd Card On Click:**

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Your Folder Name");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Your File Name";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try
    {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error" + e);
    }
```

Comment: getRealPathFromURI(...) is an interesting method since it returns a different (better) value than data.getData().getPath().

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below, you can pick up an image from gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

After that, the picked up image will be return by the onActivityResult() method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri _uri = data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Get the image file path
        final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();

        //save it the sdcard
        saveToSDCard(imageFilePath);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but also i want to see the saved image.